# Can OpenLayers show map in projection other than wgs84 or UTM, for example Albers projection?

Tags: openlayers

I've managed to show map in both utm or wgs84 in OpenLayers but Albers projection seems not possible as it does not have bound? Not sure about this, might be what I'm doing is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Albers shouldbe a valid projection, but more likely is it used locally (then you can define rectangular bounds). Could you provide more information about what you tried

Comment: Any projection you can construct with proj4 should be displayed in Openlayers.

Comment: You don't always need to specify bounds when using a proj4 definition.  This https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXNnQ.png is the output from a modified version of the OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-by-code.html which doesn't check for or set bounds.  However OpenLayers makes no attempt to handle reprojection errors and can, with some projections, crash if you pan beyond the projectable range.